# Merge Unallocated Space with a macOS Extended (Journaled) Partition via Terminal

Tags: macos, hard-drive, time-machine, disk-utility, partition

I have a 2 TB external hard drive and it contains an exFAT partition named "2 TB HDD" of 1.5 TB and a macOS Extended (Journaled) partition named "Time Machine" of 500 GB. I noticed that the Partition button in Disk Utility was greyed out when I selected the Partition Map itself, or either of the two partitions.

I decided to use a Windows machine with DiskGenius to knock the 1.5 TB partition down to 1.3 TB so I could allocate an extra 200 to the 500 GB macOS Extended (Journaled) partition, making it 700 GB.

Now I have 1.3 TB of exFAT, 200 GB of unallocated space, and 500 GB of macOS Extended (Journaled).

My question is: How can I merge the 200 GB unallocated space with the 500 GB macOS Extended (Journaled) partition using Terminal? I am aware that if I run the wrong command I could lose all of my data. This is why I am asking here — to figure out the command.

Note: DiskGenius is unable to merge these 2 together.

Comment: Have you tried in diskutil?

Comment: No. I don't know what to do or where to start. I am really worried about losing data if I do this, but I need to do it. I didn't know it wasn't easy to resize a macOS Extended (Journaled) partition. Disk Utility also can't see the 200 GB of unallocated space. I don't know if that's normal.

Comment: Oh I see - yes you've run into the MAC and Windows don't agree on where the partition info lives (sorry I didn't notice that issue first time).  You won't be able to fix that from the standard OSX tools.  I purchased a tool that does allow you to do that - but struggled to get it to work properly because it was a boot disk (needed the bootcamp partition to work properly).

Comment: This is the kind of task I'd give to [Paragon Hard Disk Manager](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/hdm-mac/) - though I'd still make sure I had everything backed up beforehand.

Comment: I have emailed them to ask whether it's possible before I pay the £30 for it.

Comment: Seems like it is, and there's a refund policy too. I will buy it. Thank you for the suggestion.